# Swagger Integration with Dropwizard

Tags: java, swagger, dropwizard, swagger-2.0

My resource structure is like:

```
@Path("/v1")
class A{
   @Path("/abc") 
   B getB(){}
   @Path("/xyz")
   C getC(){}
}
```

and in `class B` and `class C`, APIs are defined. Can you please tell me where to use `@Api()` and `@ApiOperation()` annotation. Because it's not working out for me after trying many possibilities. It is still not showing up in swagger.json

Also in `Application` class I have to add only A, not B and C.

Comment: have you looked at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/tree/master/java/java-dropwizard?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Api` at class level and `@ApiOperation` at method level. You can modify your code to the following prototype accordingly as :

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;

import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;

@Path("/v1")
@Api(value = "/v1", description = "Things at A")
class A {

    @GET
    @Path("/abc/{path}") 
    @ApiOperation(value = "Things from B", response = B.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code=HttpStatus.SC_OK, message="OK"),
            @ApiResponse(code=HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message="Server Error")
    })
    B getB(@PathParam("path") String pathParam) {
        // perform ABC task
   }

   @POST
   @Path("/xyz")
   @ApiOperation(value = "Things from B", response = C.class)
   @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code=HttpStatus.SC_OK, message="OK")
            @ApiResponse(code=HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST, message="Bad Request")
   })
    C getC(@ApiParam RequestC requestC) {
       //perform XYZ task
    }
}
```

Further in your Application class you can add in your overridden `run()` register call as  :

```
@Override
public void run(SwaggerCustomConfig config, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    environment.jersey().register(A.class);
    ....
}
```